# Specify target rules via command line from a python executable for Snakemake workflows

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am executing a Snakemake workflow via a command line python application which works more or less in this way:

```
./run.py workflowfile -argument1 -argument2...
```

In the workflow file is specified a target rule, which is passed to the "targets" argument of the Snakemake API, like this:

```
with open(workflowfile, 'rt') as fp:
    workflow_info = json.load(fp)

target = workflow_info['workflow_target']
status = snakemake.snakemake(....targets=[target]....)
```

Where "targets" must be a list.
Now, I am trying to get rid of the "workflowfile" and I want to specify via another argument the target rule name, to obtain:

```
./run.py -w "targetrulename" -a1 -a2...
```

In the Snakemake command line interface this is done in a simple way, with "target", by calling:

```
snakemake  targetrulename
```

where targetrulename is simply the name of the rule you want to be targeted. So I tried to implement a new command line argument with argparse in the following way:

```
parser.add_argument('-w', '--workflow', action="append", help='specify the workflow from the following: ')
```

and then

```
targets=args.workflow
```

but in a way or another I get different errors. Some examples:

```
-TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
-TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
-No rule to produce c  (If I type "complete" as target rule name)
```

Sorry for being noob, I just started in the field of bioinformatics (I am a biotech) and this is my first question on Stack Overflow. Hope I have done everything correctly.
Thanks for any tips or advice

edit:

the minimal example for the python script is:

```
import argparse
import snakemake

def main(args)
    snakefile=snakefile_path
    snakemake.snakemake(snakefile, configfiles=[args.configfile] …)

if __name__ == ‘__main__’
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description=””, usage=””)
    parser.add_argument(‘-c’, ‘--configfile’, action=’store’)
    [...]
    args = parser.parse_argse()
```

edit: solved

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? A small python script with argparse, snakefile, and how you invoke it?

Comment: Of course, I've edited the post. Thank you